# Translate Rails Devise error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I'm using devise gem to implement authentication in my Ruby On Rails application. Sometimes error messages are displayed such as:

> Prohibited an error being wellness saved from this user: Password is
>   too short (minimum is 6 characters)

What is the best way to translate these messages to another language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `config/locales` and copy `devise.en.yml`, giving the file a name like devise.other_language_initials.yml. Then add your own translations.

For more info on how to translate your application, go [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is downloading a translation file to the language you want. You can find more about [**in this link**](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/I18n).

What you are going to find there is a bunch of files in different languages for Devise flash notifications that you can download and add to you application under **config/locales**.

Hope that helps you! :)